# How do I troubleshoot CanoScan LIDE20 on Ubuntu 9.10 in VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, virtualbox, scanner

This may be a VirtualBox question more than anything else.  The host OS is Win7, which sees the scanner, but has no drivers for it.  VirtualBox sees & recognizes the scanner as "Cannon Scan" and shows "state captured" when I hover over USB devices.

Searching gives me many happy reports of this particular scanner being well supported, and that SANE should work with it immediately (also listedin the [Supported Hardware List](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsScannersCanon).  I get "no devices available" from XSane... and I'm not sure where else I can check.  I'd like to see if VirtualBox is telling the truth and find out if the USB port is actually being fed into the virtual OS.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of where/how to do that in Ubuntu?  Or other bright ideas.

I'm starting with a little project to add some zing to my beginner linux studies - I'm sure I haven't checked some obvious things, because I don't know them yet.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, it has been impossible to get anything beyond USB storage devices through to a guest OS in VirtualBox. I've personally tried printers and web cams.

I'm not 100% certain, but it is my understanding that the USB passthrough only supports storage devices. Quite saddening, really... So much potential lost right there...

Comment: Agreed, that's a shame.  Must be harder than it looks.